# unlawful lens Haskell

Tags: haskell, lenses

Is there a common name/type for a lens-like object that does not satisfy the property of getting out what you put in? For example something like a `listLength :: Lens [a] Int` where if you put in a length shorter than that of the source list you get a shortened list, but if you put in a longer length the original length is preserved.

Comment: Can you think of the properties that you would like such an object to have?  E.g. if you put in what you got out, you have changed nothing?

Comment: @luqui I'm just wondering if there is *any* documented concept that encompasses my example unlawful lens.

Comment: What you're talking about is very similar to [partsOf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:partsOf) which turns a traversal into a lens so long as certain invariants are held.  You can see the note in the docs for that function, but they don't actually _name_ this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lens is not just a function with the type `forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`  — it's a function with that type *that obeys certain laws*.  In particular, (as documented [in the lens docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Lens)):

1. You get back what you put in,
2. Putting back what you got doesn't change anything, and
3. Setting twice is the same as setting once.

If your function doesn't obey those laws, then it's just a function with a type that's similar to a lens.

In your particular example, `listLength` breaks the first and third laws, so it's not a lens.  That said, it would work just fine as a `Getter`, which I think is the only principle thing we can say about it.

---

More generally, it doesn't really make sense to ask about things that *lack* laws, as things tend to be defined by what laws they obey rather than what they don't obey.  For example, I pointed out that `listLength` makes a perfectly good `Getter` because it consistently extracts a value out of the `[a]` input.

So, I'll ask you: What distinguishes it from a function `listZero :: Lens [a] Int` that always emits `0`?  Can you come up with a general law that `listLength` obeys that `listZero` doesn't?  If so, then you have something to actually look for in the current literature: that is, `listLength` is one of a set of functions that obeys some (possibly interesting) law.  If not, then you just have a function with a type that makes it look like a lens.

Comment: `listLength` obeys a standard-ish round-trip-and-a-half law, while `listZero` may not, depending on its implementation of the "put" direction. The law in question is this: if `put v x = v'`, then `put v' (get v') = v'`. In some older literature, obeying two round-trip-and-a-half laws was enough to call a thing a lens; well-behaved lenses also obeyed your (1) and (2); and the things now available from the `lens` package that obey all three of your laws were called very well-behaved lenses.