# Is it possible to model update with constrains with Lens (or other optics)?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, haskell-lens, lenses, monocle-scala

I'm working with an Web UI which requires validation on user inputs. When implementing an double thumb slider, and comes problem when using Lens with a 'constraint' update. When use `lens.set`, it is required to validate the new value, and if it is not valid up to a given constraint, a closest valid value should be updated instead. The validation is a composition of multiple simple rulers.

I can't find a proper lens to model this 'decorated' kind of `set` or `modify`.

---

I'm using following models, (using [monocle-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts))

```ts
import { Lens } from "monocle-ts";
interface State {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}
// assuming start < end always holds

const center = ({ start, end }: State): number => (start + end) / 2;
const length = ({ start, end }: State): number => end - start;

const startLens: Lens<State, number> = Lens.fromProp<State>()("start");
// Models direct drag start (left) thumb

const endLens: Lens<State, number> = Lens.fromProp<State>()("end");
// Models direct drag end (right) thumb

const centerLens: Lens<State, number> = new Lens<State, number>(
  center,
  (newCenter) => (s) => {
    const l = length(s);
    return { start: newCenter - l / 2, end: newCenter + l / 2 };
  }
); 
// Models direct drag slider, i.e. move the 'track' of two thumb slider, only chage center while prserve length.

const lengthLens: Lens<State, number> = new Lens<State, number>(
  length,
  (newLength) => (s) => {
    const c = center(s);
    return { start: c - newLength / 2, end: c + newLength / 2 };
  }
);
// Models scale the range, change length while preserve center
```

Every things works fine before there comes a constraint on length. I want to get something like 'step length', thus the length of state is required to be integer multiple of a given step. A first try is something like the following:

```ts
const lengthStepLens = (step: number): Lens<State, number> =>
  new Lens<State, number>(length, (newLength) => (s) => {
    const stepLength = Math.round(newLength / step) * step;
    const c = center(s);
    return { start: c - stepLength / 2, end: c + stepLength / 2 };
  });
```

Although it seems work on keep length step constraint satisfied, however the `lengthStepLens` above seems breaks lens law:

```
get(set(a)(s)) = a
```

e.g. if `step = 1`,

```
const l = lengthStepLens(1);
const s: State = { start: 0.0, end: 1.0 };
const a: number = 0.9;
console.log(l.get(l.set(a)(s))); // prints 1, != 0.9
```

The law only works on 'valid' new values.

---

Another approach is use an separate validation and correction logic, but I'm missing two advantage of using lens:

1. abstract actual state representation from user update logic (i.e. component accept generic state `T` and `Lens<T, number>` works)
2. composing multiple constraints (rulers) seems just like lifted version of composing lenses. There are actually other constrains like `min`, `max` constraint on `start` and `end`. composing constrains seems like some 'monadic' chaining of lenses, maybe something like

```ts
function merge<S, A>(la: Lens<S, A>, lb: Lens<S, A>): Lens<S, A> {
  // assumes:
  // forall s, if s is valid on both la and lb, la.get(s) === lb.get(s)
  // forall a, s, lb.set(a)(la.set(a)(s)) is still valid on la
  return new Lens(
    (s) => la.get(s),
    (a) => (s) => lb.set(a)(la.set(a)(s))
  );
}
```

---

Question:

- Is a there correct optics with law satisfied for this problem?
- What would happen when using lens with laws broken?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65376307/8289918

Comment: You could use a newtype for valid steps, such as [`NonNegativeInteger`](https://gcanti.github.io/newtype-ts/modules/NonNegativeInteger.ts.html) from `newtype-ts`. This would ensure that the set-get law holds, but has a small runtime cost.